# How to filter data based on dateTime in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am reading list of messages from servcie and displaying in a format.The json data I am getiing from servcie is:

```
{"item": [
      {
      "createDtTm": "2015-12-04T15:24:16.094-06:00",
      "folder": 1 , 
      "from": "abc@test.com",
      "itemId": "41",
      "itemType":"MESSAGE"
      "read": "true",
      "subject": "Here is a test message",
      "toDirectAddress": "xyz@test.com"
   },
      {
      "createDtTm": "2015-12-07T15:24:16.094-06:00",
      "folder":  1,
      "from": "abc@test.com",
      "itemId": "41",
      "itemType":"MESSAGE"
      "read": "true",
      "subject": "Here is a test message",
      "toDirectAddress": "xyz@test.com"
   },
      {
      "createDtTm": "2015-12-05T15:24:16.094-06:00",
      "folder": 1,
      "from": "abc@test.com",
      "itemId": "41",
      "itemType":"MESSAGE"
      "read": "true",
      "subject": "Here is a test message",
      "toDirectAddress": "xyz@test.com"
   }
]}
```

using this data, I am trying to display in a view like, the messages having todays date, under Todays, yesterdays messages under yesterday, similarly how it displayed in outlook email. How do I display in that format in angular js?

```
Today
   msg1 6:00PM
   msg2 5.00AM
yesterday
   msg3
   msg4
one week ago
   msg4
```

Here is my service call:

```
var promise = $http.post(urlBase + '/' + 'getData')
                   .success(function(data){
               dataList = data;               
               return dataList ;
           })
                   .error(function(data){                    
                    dataList= 'error';                   
                    return dataList;   
           });
           return promise;   
        },
```

Here is my controller methods:

```
$scope.dataList = function(){
  return Service.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for an Angular grid.

Try this...

http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on view template (html)

```
<div ng-show="{{dataList != 'error'}}" ng-repeat="message in dataList | orderby : message.createDtTm ">
    <div>
        {{message.createDtTm | myDateFilter }}
        message.subject            
    </div>
</div>
```

in you app register a filter named myDateFilter

```
yourApp.filter('myDateFilter', function(){
     return function(input){
        var today = new Date();
        var result = null;
        var val = null;
        if(input)
        { 
            val = new Date();
        }
        else
        {
            val = new Date(input);
        }
        if(val.getTime() < date.getTime())
        {
            result = "Yesterday";
        }
        else if(val.getTime() == date.get)
        {
            result = "Today";
        }
        else
        {
            //SO on your date logic
        }
        return result;
     }   
    });
```